# Maintaining a footer strip of background with CSS

Tags: html, css

Our design team has come up with a concept that uses a full background image on the landing page, but then only has the image on the footer of the remaining pages, with the main content being on a white background.

So, as a quick mock up to illustrate the concept, the landing page might be:

[image]

While the majority of the site would be:

[image]

This presents a problem because we obviously don't know the window size it's being displayed in, so it keep that footer strip consistent across all pages I presumably have to use a whole-page background image and then block most of it out in white.

I am struggling to do this in CSS (I'm a back-end developer that's been roped in to do this ). I adopted the following pattern for a sticky footer:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url("iStock-507452790.jpg");
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 50px;
}

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      content!
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer!
  </footer>
</body>
```

But this just leads to the whole page being filled with the background colour specified on the wrapper.

Is there a way to get white on most of the page and just keep the strip at the bottom? I am not averse to using other sticky footer methods if necessary.

Comment: So, you want to have the `footer` always displayed as the background image? Also, why do you have a `min-width:100%;` for your wrapper? Or is this to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @Rubenxfd Sorry if I've not explained it very well. I want the footer to always show a the same portion of the background image which would be at the bottom of the page if it was full-page. Does that make sense? There's not a min-width on the wrapper - it's min-height?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') center 
  center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  content!
  <footer class="footer">
    footer!
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think you have the problem the wrong way round. I want the footer to be always showing its respective portion of a background image, not a different colour?

Comment: Okay then you can put the footer in wrapper with position

Answer (score 1):

I also have changed the DOM a little. Hope this helps.

Also you can remove the footer text if you dont need it.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://www.lavitaoggi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/8e69oceano-acqua-bolle-aria-ossigeno.jpg');
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 90vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  content! loream
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  footer!s
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - your sample is exactly what I'm after. On my page it's showing the top of the image rather than the bottom in the footer which is ... odd. I will dig.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.page{
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://ulatbambu.com/images/google-images-water-background-clipart-35.jpg');
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  width:100%;
}

.footer, .push {
      height: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
      content!
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <span>footer!</span>
  </footer>
 </div>
</body>
```

Try this